# Where to get Aegisub?

Tags: 12.10, package-management, deb, source, subtitle

Where can I get new Aegisub? Ubuntu reps have only 2.1.9 which is VERY buggy (it doesn't support cyrillic lower case, it's unaceptable for me). I found only source, but I'm not sure, that I can do everything right. Where to get new package (at least newer)?

Comment: As this was your first question on askubuntu: It is very helpful to other users if you mark the answer that helped you. If something went wrong, leave feedback and we will be happy to help you. Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have two options: compile from source (which is easy if you follow the instructions) or use a precompiled package for 12.04 with your 12.10 version. In both cases you will get `aegisub 3.0.1`.

## Install from precompiled package

[On this page](http://dl.jikan.fr/Applications/) someone provides precompiled packages of aegisub and wxWidgets (install both packages) for Ubuntu 12.04. Despite the warning that the package is of low quality, the installation should work with Ubuntu 12.10 as well.

## Compile from source

I've found step by step instructions in the [aegisub forum](http://forum.aegisub.org/viewtopic.php?f=10&t=65482). Please take a look at the post, the poster explains all steps.

A short version in case the link goes down:

- Install dependencies:  Open a terminal (<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>) and insert the following:
  `sudo apt-get install build-essential libasound2-dev libass-dev libffms2-dev libfftw3-dev libgl1-mesa-dev libglu1-mesa-dev libgtk2.0-dev libhunspell-dev liblua5.1-dev checkinstall`
- Build wxWidgets by entering the following into the terminal (line for line):
  `cd ~

  wget http://sourceforge.net/projects/wxwindows/files/latest/wxWidgets-2.9.4.tar.bz2

  tar xjf wxWidgets-2.9.4.tar.bz2

  cd wxWidgets-2.9.4

  ./configure --with-opengl

  make

  sudo checkinstall

  sudo ldconfig`
- Build aegisub by entering the following into the terminal (line for line):
  `cd ~

  wget http://ftp.aegisub.org/pub/releases/aegisub-3.0.1.tar.xz

  tar xJf aegisub-3.0.1.tar.xz

  cd aegisub-3.0.1/aegisub

  ./configure

  make

  sudo checkinstall`

Comment: I installed deb, but Aegisub does not start

Comment: Is there an error message? Try to start it from a terminal (CTRL+ALT+T) with the command `aegisub-3.0.1`. If you installed from the precompiled packages, did you also install the wxWidgets package [from here](http://dl.jikan.fr/Applications/Ubuntu/12.04/wxWidgets/2.9.4/) (sorry, didn't point this out in my answer)?